# 'No such file or directory' if process is run programmatically (from C#)

Tags: c#, linux, hadoop, process, mono

I have an application that dumps a lot of files to a directory. I want to copy these files to a Hadoop cluster using the hadoop command. I use the following code to run the command.

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo export = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
export.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
export.RedirectStandardError = false;
export.UseShellExecute = false;
export.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
export.FileName = "hadoop";
export.Arguments = "fs -copyFromLocal " + Path.Combine(dumpDirectory, "*.txt") + " " + hadoopPath));
Console.WriteLine("Copying data: hadoop " + export.Arguments);

System.Diagnostics.Process proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(export);

proc.WaitForExit();
if (proc.ExitCode == 0)
{
    IEnumerable<string> files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(dumpDirectory);
    foreach (string file in files)
        File.Delete(file);
}
else
    Console.WriteLine("Error copying to Hadoop: " + proc.ExitCode);
```

The program writes the following message:

> Copying data: hadoop fs -copyFromLocal local/directory/*.txt /user/remote/directory/
>
> copyFromLocal: `local/directory/*.txt': No such file or directory
>
> Error copying to Hadoop: 1

Interestingly, when I run the command manually, the files copy without error.

Also, if the program runs the command without using `*.txt` and instead calls the command for each file individually, the command succeeds.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: try to set DumpDirectory to ./local/directory/*.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I partially resolved the problem by creating a bash script containing the given command. I ran the bash script programmatically and it worked.

However, I still do not know why the original did not work.